# Python Selenium errors

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, runtime-error

I was using Selenium to scrap data from a website. The first element in a for loop went well, until the second one on. Then I tried with different possible solutions such as

`pip3 uninstall requests[security]`, then installed it again;

set `time.sleep(5)`;

downgraded my selenium from 3.9 to 3.8;

tried with different browsers, first Chrome then Safari, but I got different errors for each of them.

Chrome: `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`

Safari: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>`

All the methods were helpless. I believe the website might have detected automated activities and blocked my IP address if they could. Otherwise, I can't explain why the first element in my for loop went through.

Are there any solutions to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: The errors you mentioned in your question, on what codeline they arise?Can you show us your code and the link of the webpage your are testing? It will help us to find an answer for your problem.

Comment: @lloyd, I used explicit waits and removed a `driver.quit()` that I threw in randomly and it worked fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank, just got it worked. Thanks anyway!